# Help to understand the proof of the cardinality of a Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

I was reading the proof of this theorem:

[image]

The proof is as follows:

[image]
[image]

I understand the entire proof except for the conclusion:

> Because $h$ is bijective $\dots$

Why is it sufficient to show that the formula for the cardinality of $|A \times B|$ is $|A|.|B|$ for all nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ if $h$ bijective? Are there properties of of a bijection function that this proof is relying on but did not mention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you’re missing is the definition of the cardinality of a set. By definition two sets have the same cardinality if there is a bijection between them. The proof establishes the existence of a bijection $h$ between $A\times B$ and the set $\{1,2,\ldots,np\}$; the cardinality of $\{1,2,\ldots,np\}$ is $np$ by definition, so $|A\times B|=np$. Finally, $n=|A|$ and $p=|B|$, so $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot|B|$.